# Recursive tree function traversal

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, treeview

I have a tree that represents an excel function, where node contains name : function_name (for example SUM);type : function_type (function or number); arguments : function_ arguments. The whole problem for me is that arguments can be another function. I already have an algorithm that works on simple functions, but with a lot of nesting, arguments are lost. I would like to know how to solve this. I will attach my code below.

```
function getSubFormulas(node) {
  if (node.type === "function") {
    var args = node.arguments.map(arg => {
   console.log(arg)
      if (arg.arguments) {
        // Если аргумент - это массив, извлекаем свойство name из каждого элемента
        console.log(arg.arguments.map(subArg => getSubFormulas(subArg).name).join(","))
        return arg.name +"(" +arg.arguments.map(subArg => getSubFormulas(subArg).name).join(",") + ")";
      } else {
        // Если аргумент не является массивом, извлекаем свойство name
        return getSubFormulas(arg).name;
      }
    }).join(",");
    console.log(args + " args ")
    
    var name = `${node.name}(${args})`;
  //  console.log(name);
    const formula = {
      name: name,
      depth: node.depth
    };
    return [formula, ...node.arguments.filter((elem) => elem.type == "function").map(getSubFormulas).flat()];
  } else {
    if (node.operand == null) {
      let temp_name = node.value;
      return {name: temp_name}
    }
    let temp_name = 0 - node.operand.value;
    return {name : temp_name}
  }
}
```

Formula of the form

```
=SUM(MAX(3,5),AVERAGE (1,2,3,4,SUM(MAX(1,3),AVERAGE (SUM(2,3,4,4),MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2)))),ABS(SUM(-7,4,1)))
```

looks like

```
{
    "type": "function",
    "name": "SUM",
    "arguments": [
        {
            "type": "function",
            "name": "MAX",
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "value": 3,
                    "depth": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "value": 5,
                    "depth": 2
                }
            ],
            "depth": 1
        },
        {
            "type": "function",
            "name": "AVERAGE",
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "value": 1,
                    "depth": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "value": 2,
                    "depth": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "value": 3,
                    "depth": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "value": 4,
                    "depth": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "function",
                    "name": "SUM",
                    "arguments": [
                        {
                            "type": "function",
                            "name": "MAX",
                            "arguments": [
                                {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "depth": 4
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "number",
                                    "value": 3,
                                    "depth": 4
                                }
                            ],
                            "depth": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "function",
                            "name": "AVERAGE",
                            "arguments": [
                                {
                                    "type": "function",
                                    "name": "SUM",
                                    "arguments": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 2,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 3,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 4,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 4,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "depth": 4
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "function",
                                    "name": "MAX",
                                    "arguments": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 2,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 2,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "value": 2,
                                            "depth": 5
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "depth": 4
                                }
                            ],
                            "depth": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "depth": 2
                }
            ],
            "depth": 1
        },
        {
            "type": "function",
            "name": "ABS",
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "type": "function",
                    "name": "SUM",
                    "arguments": [
                        {
                            "type": "unary-expression",
                            "operator": "-",
                            "operand": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "value": 7
                            },
                            "depth": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "number",
                            "value": 4,
                            "depth": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "number",
                            "value": 1,
                            "depth": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "depth": 2
                }
            ],
            "depth": 1
        }
    ],
    "depth": 0
}
```

And expected output

```
[
    {
        "name": "SUM(MAX(3,5),AVERAGE(1,2,3,4,SUM(MAX(1,3),AVERAGE(SUM(2,3,4,4),MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2)))),ABS(SUM(-7,4,1)))",
        "depth": 0,
        "res": "11,1"
    },
    {
        "name": "MAX(3,5)",
        "depth": 1,
        "res": "5"
    },
    {
        "name": "AVERAGE(1,2,3,4,SUM(,))",
        "depth": 1,
        "res": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "SUM(MAX(1,3),AVERAGE(,))",
        "depth": 2,
        "res": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": "MAX(1,3)",
        "depth": 3,
        "res": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": "AVERAGE(SUM(2,3,4,4),MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2))",
        "depth": 3,
        "res": "7,5"
    },
    {
        "name": "SUM(2,3,4,4)",
        "depth": 4,
        "res": "13"
    },
    {
        "name": "MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2)",
        "depth": 4,
        "res": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "ABS(SUM(-7,4,1))",
        "depth": 1,
        "res": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "SUM(-7,4,1)",
        "depth": 2,
        "res": "-2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your `node` object?

Comment: @gog Formula of the form =SUM(MAX(3,5),AVERAGE (1,2,3,4,SUM(MAX(1,3),AVERAGE (SUM(2,3,4,4),MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2)))),ABS(SUM(-7,4,1)))

Comment: @gog {"type":"function","name":"SUM","arguments":[{"type":"function","name":"MAX","arguments":[{"type":"number","value":3,"depth":2},{"type":"number","value":5,"depth":2}],"depth":1},{"type":"function","name":"AVERAGE","arguments":[{"type":"number","value":1,"depth":2},{"type":"number","value":2,"depth":2},{"type":"number","value":3,"depth":2},{"type":"number","value":4,"depth":2},{"type":"function","name":"SUM","arguments":[{"type":"function","name":"MAX","arguments":[{"type":"number","value":1,"depth":4},{"type":"number","value":3,"depth":4}],"depth":3},

Comment: What output do you expect from that?

Comment: {"type":"function","name":"AVERAGE","arguments":[{"type":"function","name":"SUM","arguments":[{"type":"number","value":2,"depth":5},{"type":"number","value":3,"depth":5},{"type":"number","value":4,"depth":5},{"type":"number","value":4,"depth":5}],"depth":4},{"type":"function","name":"MAX","arguments":[{"type":"number","value":1,"depth":5},{"type":"number","value":2,"depth":5},{"type":"number","value":1,"depth":5},{"type":"number","value":2,"depth":5},{"type":"number","value":1,"depth":5},

Comment: {"type":"number","value":2,"depth":5}],"depth":4}],"depth":3}],"depth":2}],"depth":1},{"type":"function","name":"ABS","arguments":[{"type":"function","name":"SUM","arguments":[{"type":"unary-expression","operator":"-","operand":{"type":"number","value":7},"depth":3},{"type":"number","value":4,"depth":3},{"type":"number","value":1,"depth":3}],"depth":2}],"depth":1}],"depth":0}

Comment: @James array [{"name":"SUM(MAX(3,5),AVERAGE(1,2,3,4,SUM(MAX(1,3),AVERAGE(SUM(2,3,4,4),MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2)))),ABS(SUM(-7,4,1)))","depth":0,"res":"11,1"},{"name":"MAX(3,5)","depth":1,"res":"5"},{"name":"AVERAGE(1,2,3,4,SUM(,))","depth":1,"res":"2"},{"name":"SUM(MAX(1,3),AVERAGE(,))","depth":2,"res":"3"},{"name":"MAX(1,3)","depth":3,"res":"3"},{"name":"AVERAGE(SUM(2,3,4,4),MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2))","depth":3,"res":"7,5"},{"name":"SUM(2,3,4,4)","depth":4,"res":"13"},{"name":"MAX(1,2,1,2,1,2)","depth":4,"res":"2"},{"name":"ABS(SUM(-7,4,1))","depth":1,"res":"2"},{"name":"SUM(-7,4,1)","depth":2,"res":"-2"}]

Comment: Please edit your question with all that data, and format it so it doesn't make our eyes bleed.

Comment: given that you have these `res` fields in your expected input, is the goal to actually _evaluate_ the formula, or just reconstruct it from the AST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I used two functions, getFormula recursively gets the formula for a node, and walkTree recursively builds the output objects into a flat array.

```js
const getFormula = (node) => {
  if (node.type === "function") {
    if (node.arguments) {
      return node.name + "(" + node.arguments.map(getFormula).join(",") + ")";
    } 
    return node.name + "()";
  } else if (node.type === "unary-expression") {
    if (node.operator === "-") {
      return -node.operand.value;
    }
  } 
  return node.value;
};

const walkTree = (node, output=[], depth=0) => {
  if (node.type === "function") {
    output.push({
      name: getFormula(node),
      depth
    });
    if (node.arguments) {
      node.arguments.forEach(arg => walkTree(arg, output, depth + 1));
    }
  }
  return output;
};

let testNode = {
  "type": "function",
  "name": "SUM",
  "arguments": [
    {
      "type": "function",
      "name": "MAX",
      "arguments": [
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 3,
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 5,
          "depth": 2
        }
      ],
      "depth": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "function",
      "name": "AVERAGE",
      "arguments": [
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 1,
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 2,
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 3,
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 4,
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "function",
          "name": "SUM",
          "arguments": [
            {
              "type": "function",
              "name": "MAX",
              "arguments": [
                {
                  "type": "number",
                  "value": 1,
                  "depth": 4
                },
                {
                  "type": "number",
                  "value": 3,
                  "depth": 4
                }
              ],
              "depth": 3
            },
            {
              "type": "function",
              "name": "AVERAGE",
              "arguments": [
                {
                  "type": "function",
                  "name": "SUM",
                  "arguments": [
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 2,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 3,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 4,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 4,
                      "depth": 5
                    }
                  ],
                  "depth": 4
                },
                {
                  "type": "function",
                  "name": "MAX",
                  "arguments": [
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 1,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 2,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 1,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 2,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 1,
                      "depth": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "number",
                      "value": 2,
                      "depth": 5
                    }
                  ],
                  "depth": 4
                }
              ],
              "depth": 3
            }
          ],
          "depth": 2
        }
      ],
      "depth": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "function",
      "name": "ABS",
      "arguments": [
        {
          "type": "function",
          "name": "SUM",
          "arguments": [
            {
              "type": "unary-expression",
              "operator": "-",
              "operand": {
                "type": "number",
                "value": 7
              },
              "depth": 3
            },
            {
              "type": "number",
              "value": 4,
              "depth": 3
            },
            {
              "type": "number",
              "value": 1,
              "depth": 3
            }
          ],
          "depth": 2
        }
      ],
      "depth": 1
    }
  ],
  "depth": 0
};

let result = walkTree(testNode);
console.log(result);
```